# How To Predict If Two Lables Have Same Graphs

Tags: machine-learning

I have encountered a challenge where the visualization of the feature set in comparison to the labels revealed strikingly similar paths across all graphs. This uniformity presents a significant obstacle as it suggests a lack of discriminatory power among features in predicting the labels. Despite attempts to mitigate this issue by employing K-Nearest Neighbors (KNN), the approach yielded unsatisfactory results, indicating the ineffectiveness of this method in our context.

This is the picture of my features and label
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuemv.jpg)